# swap value in array java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a question here.
i tried to find the first missing positive number in this array.
like [1,2,0] the answer should be 3.
the code is:

```
public static int firstMissingPositive(int[] A) {
        // Start typing your Java solution below
        // DO NOT write main() function
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
            while(A[i]>0 && A[i]<=A.length && A[i]!=i+1 && A[i]!=A[A[i]-1] ){

                 int temp=A[A[i]-1];
               A[A[i]-1] = A[i];
               A[i]=temp;
            }
        }
        int index=0;
        while(index<A.length && A[index]==index+1) index++;
        return index+1;

  }
```

This is working.
while when i change the swap function inside the code like this way:

```
int temp=A[i];
A[i]=A[A[i]-1];
A[A[i]-1]=temp;
```

This time the code take a long time to compile and not working. why?
The solution is right here. Just question about the swap function inside.
Your algorithm should run in O(n) time and uses constant space.
updated: @Bohemian your answer is completely wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we observe the 2nd and 3rd lines `A[i]` is being changed in the second line and being reused in the third. So this will throw and error.

Instead use :

```
temp = A[i];
A[i] = A[A[i]-1];
A[temp-1] = temp;
```

`temp` instead of `A[i]` will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
int temp=A[i];
A[i]=A[i-1];
A[i-1]=temp;
```

You were mixing your array values with your indexes. While technically your code compiled, because your array contains `int`s, it will not do anything usefull and will likely explode with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You may consider renaming your array variable to conform to java naming standards; start with a lowercase letter, eg `numbers`

---

As food for thought, I would sort the array like this:

```
Arrays.sort(A);
```

Comment: no, your answer is complete wrong. the answer should be mine if i want to get the first missing positive number. you don't get the idea of the question.

Comment: sorting the array will take more than O(n)time.

Comment: @Bohemian This question is finding the First missing positives . What the user is doing is that They are swapping the elements to their respective positions . So if we do A[i] = A[i-1] then you would not get correct answer. we will not ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because we are already checking for A[i] < A.length in the while loop. Do any body has any idea ?